# Why does saving my cloud formation designer to S3 bucket hang?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, bucket

When I try to save it from the visual designer I get

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if you are in the wrong region.  us-east-2 in this case.

Switching my region to us-east-1 (N. Virginia)

[image]

results in:

[image]